# Find the maximum value of the expression

Tags: inequality

Let a,b,c,d be positive real numbers. Show that

> $$\frac{(ab+bc+ca)}{(a^3+b^3+c^3)}+\frac{(ab+bd+da)}{(a^3+b^3+d^3)}+\frac{(ac+cd+da)}{(a^3+c^3+d^3)}+\frac{ (bc+cd+db)}{(b^3+c^3+d^3)} \le \frac{(a^2+b^2)}{(ab)^{3/2}} + \frac{(c^2+d^2)}{(cd)^{3/2}} +\frac{(a^2+c^2)}{(ac)^{3/2}} + \frac{(b^2+d^2)}{(bd)^{3/2}} +\frac{ (a^2+d^2)}{(ad)^{3/2}} + \frac{(b^2+c^2)}{(bc)^{3/2}}$$

Comment: i am very sorry to inform you that i do not have any kind of LATEX software i wish anyone could edit the question

Comment: i did not understand and the present keyboard what i have does not have some keys

Comment: Do you need the "minimum" on the RHS? Minimum of RHS does not exist, as it can be made arbitrarily close to zero by picking large values for $a, b, c, d$. And LHS can clearly exceed zero.

Comment: the brackets minimum[...] indicate  minimum of whole expression contained in the brackets. it would be nice if it would have been replaced by a long flower brackets

Comment: yes i think we need minimum on RHS

Comment: i mean that LHS is less than or equal to minimum of RHS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\displaystyle \frac{a^2+b^2}{(ab)^{3/2}} \ge 2\frac{a^2+b^2}{a^3+b^3}$ by AM-GM.  Using that, we get
$$\frac{a^2+b^2}{(ab)^{3/2}}+\frac{b^2+c^2}{(b c)^{3/2}}+\frac{c^2+a^2}{(c a)^{3/2}} \ge  2\left(\frac{a^2+b^2}{a^3+b^3} + \frac{b^2+c^2}{b^3+c^3} + \frac{c^2+a^2}{c^3+a^3} \right) \tag{1}$$

Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality on the RHS of $(1)$ above, we have
$$\frac{a^2+b^2}{(ab)^{3/2}}+\frac{b^2+c^2}{(b c)^{3/2}}+\frac{c^2+a^2}{(c a)^{3/2}} \ge 2\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{a^3+b^3+c^3} \ge 6\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a^3+b^3+c^3} \tag{2}$$

Now cyclically summing four similar expressions using $(2)$, we get
$$\sum_{sym} \frac{a^2+b^2}{(ab)^{3/2}} \ge 2\sum_{sym} \frac{ab+bc+ca}{a^3+b^3+c^3}$$
which is tighter than the inequality in your problem...